# Moving channels from deleted category to new category

Tags: python, discord.py

**Discord.py**

I am going to try to explain this as well as I can.

I have an even to where if a category is deleted; the category gets cloned.
With the deleted channel data, I would like to move the channels from that original category to the new category.

The code I am currently using is:

```
    @commands.Cog.listener() 
    async def on_guild_channel_delete(self,channel):
        try:
            logs = await channel.guild.audit_logs(limit=1, action=discord.AuditLogAction.channel_delete).flatten()
            logs = logs[0]
            if logs.user != channel.guild.owner:
                if logs.user.id != 891409650287796295:
                    new = await channel.clone(reason="Anti Nuke Protection")
                    try:
                        channels = channel.channels
                        print(channels)
                        for c in channels:
                            try:
                                await c.edit(category=new)
                            except Exception as e:
                                print(e)
                    except Exception as e:
                        print(e)
        except:
            pass
```

But the channels variable returns as *[ ]*

Comment: Just to make sure: If the category is deleted, all the channels appear at the top. Do you want them to then be moved to the new category? Also: What is your code doing? You are talking about categories and channels. Please explain the code a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I think that when this function is called, the category `channel` is already deleted. So it does not have any channels in it, which means `channel.channels` will logically be empty.